# iframe with scripplet jsp in src

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

I am working in iframe with a scrippplet in the src, but it is not working

```
<iframe src="<%=urlProdMatch%>" width="550" height="500" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

However, urlProdMatch has a url

```
<h4><%=urlProdMatch%></h4>
```

It prints the value the url, but in the iframe shows nothing

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the source for the IFrame? (i think they're evil, by the way)
My guess is the the data is being written out, but it gets written between the script brackets and therefore doesn't show up.
Try this version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write("BUT THIS DOES PRINT!"); 
</script>
<%
  response.getWriter().println("THIS DOESN'T PRINT");
 %>
```